# how to find values greater than 500 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my code, but i'm not able to understand that why it is giving me value 13.000 in the output.

```
    data[data.Fare>500].index
    output: Int64Index([258, 679, 737, 343], dtype='int64')
    
    data.iloc[[258, 679, 737, 343], 9]
    output: 
    258    512.3292
    679    512.3292
    737    512.3292
    343     13.0000
    Name: Fare, dtype: float64
```

Comment: If use `data[data.Fare>500]` then got same ouput?

Comment: yes, it also gave me 13.000 and I'm not sure why

Comment: I got an answer, there are two rows with the same index 343 which containing values 512.3292 and 13.000 respectivly.